# How can I create a multi-line input box

Tags: vb6, inputbox

I'm trying to create an input box in VB6 where I will be able to include spaces in the PROMPT. I've tried to do the same thing I do with MSGBOX but it's not letting me do VBCRLF. here's what i'm looking to do

```
This company has more than 1 department.
For Accounting type 1
For Reasearch  type 2
```

input box in here and the OK and CANCEL to the right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will display a multi-line prompt string:

```
Dim ret As String
Dim prompt As String

prompt = "This company has more than 1 department." & vbCrLf & _
    "For Accounting type 1" & vbCrLf & _
    "For Reasearch  type 2"


ret = InputBox$(prompt)
```